# How to change repo branch/tag after repo init url -b TAG?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I did

```
TAG_NAME=RQ1A.210105.003.2021.01.05.03
mkdir grapheneos-$TAG_NAME
cd grapheneos-$TAG_NAME
repo init -u https://github.com/GrapheneOs/platform_manifest.git -b refs/tags/$TAG_NAME
```

and compiled everything. Actually, it was not `GrapheneOS` profile but my own profile which has a fork of it. Then, I changed some things on the xml on the fork. Is there a way I can point to the new TAG without having to delete all the repo and doing repo init again? I already spent some hours compiling everything and didnt want to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the new TAG, if you mean the one specified in `repo init` after `-b`, you could just run `repo init -u https://github.com/GrapheneOs/platform_manifest.git -b $NEW_TAG_NAME` and `repo sync` to update the repositories.

Which repositories are downloaded and which revision is checked out are decided by the manifest. So if you want to use a specific manifest, you could also simply copy that manifest to somewhere and run `repo sync -m $path`. Here `$path` could be the absolute path to the manifest or its relative path in `.repo/manifests` if it's been placed under `.repo/manifests`.